# Resources for implementing MVVM (ViewModel) pattern in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, viewmodel, mvvm

Can anyone direct me towards some code or a tutorial for implementing the ViewModel in Flex 3?

All I'm finding on the web are examples for Silverlight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Martin Fowler has also written about these ideas in the past under the term "[Presentation Model](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html)". So you might find useful tutorials under that search phrase as well since it's not an "MS invented term". :-)

Indeed, [this MS overview material](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) acknowledges Fowler's work directly

> In 2005, John Gossman, currently one
>   of the WPF and Silverlight Architects
>   at Microsoft, unveiled the
>   Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) pattern on
>   his blog. MVVM is identical to
>   Fowler's Presentation Model, in that
>   both patterns feature an abstraction
>   of a View, which contains a View's
>   state and behavior. Fowler introduced
>   Presentation Model as a means of
>   creating a UI platform-independent
>   abstraction of a View, whereas Gossman
>   introduced MVVM as a standardized way
>   to leverage core features of WPF to
>   simplify the creation of user
>   interfaces. In that sense, I consider
>   MVVM to be a specialization of the
>   more general PM pattern, tailor-made
>   for the WPF and Silverlight platforms.

Comment: +1 for schooling me and for appropriate use of the dollar sign

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to share a comparison I wrote up of MVVM (Silverlight) vs PresentionModel (Flex).  It shows how the two implementations of the same pattern differ/compare:

http://houseofbilz.com/archives/2010/12/29/cross-training-in-silverlight-flexmvvm-vs-presentation-model/

Answer (score 1):

The reason all of the examples your finding are for Silverlight is because MVVM is by-and-large a Microsoft invention. It has to do with the ease of tying WPF views with data. The "ViewModel" is little more than a way of describing a subset of functions performed by the Controller in a traditional MVC design model; [some MVVM descriptions](http://www.orbifold.net/default/wp-content/uploads/MVVM.jpg) even include a controller.

With that said, it doesn't really matter whether your app follows the MVVM or MVC models precisely. It's more of a high-level, organizational idea that should guide your design and development. If you're totally clueless about the models you can find any number of [quickie web tutorials](http://www.slideshare.net/Antonos/mvc-pattern-flex-implementation-of-mvc-presentation), and probably some printed literature on the subject.